How to modify the frame step using handlers?
I would like to modify the frame step right before and after the rendering process. This is what I tried:
import bpy

def step_change(scene):
    scene.frame_step = 5

def change_back(scene):
    scene.frame_step = 1

bpy.app.handlers.render_init.append(step_change)
bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(change_back)

Although I visibly see that the step gets changed to 5 during the rendering process, Blender still renders every frame. What am I missing?
